# Do I need to put some grease on free hub or keep it dry?

Tags: freehub, grease

[image]

I have a dilemma with put on some grease on the freehub body or not. Because some people recommend to keep it dry?

Answer (score 4):

It never hurts to put a very light (invisible) coating of grease on exposed bare metal surfaces.  But the grease should not be put on painted metal or on plastics.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What kind of grease do you recommend?

Comment: Whatever's on hand.